# mouse issue after upgrade to ubuntu 18.04

Tags: upgrade, mouse

Yesterday I upgraded from Ubuntu 16.10 to 18.04 via terminal, so issuing the following commands

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt dist-upgrade
sudo apt autoremove
```

then I changed some file in the `/etc` directory (can't find that page with the instructions I followed any more) and then I issued

```
sudo apt do-release-upgrade
```

Everything fine on the page where one chooses the account: the cursor moves correctly in all directions. However after the OS loads, the mouse cursor can only move vertically close to the right edge of the screen. I can still click the link and objects that are on its way, but it does not follow my movements on the touchpad. So I don't know where the problem lies.

Can anyone spot the problem or has encountered a similar issue? Thanks

**UPDATE**

To move the cursor in all directions I must hold the left button of the mouse pressed.

**UPDATE 2**

Output of `uname -a`:

```
Linux gigi 4.15.0-43-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Thu Dec 6 14:45:28 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Output of `sudo lshw -C memory`:

```
  *-firmware                
       description: BIOS
       vendor: LENOVO
       physical id: 0
       version: DCCN34WW(V2.03)
       date: 12/01/2015
       size: 128KiB
       capacity: 6080KiB
       capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect edd int13floppynec int13floppytoshiba int13floppy360 int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int9keyboard int10video acpi usb biosbootspecification uefi
  *-cache:0
       description: L1 cache
       physical id: 6
       slot: L1 Cache
       size: 64KiB
       capacity: 64KiB
       capabilities: synchronous internal write-back instruction
       configuration: level=1
  *-cache:1
       description: L2 cache
       physical id: 7
       slot: L2 Cache
       size: 512KiB
       capacity: 512KiB
       capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=2
  *-cache:2
       description: L3 cache
       physical id: 8
       slot: L3 Cache
       size: 3MiB
       capacity: 3MiB
       capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=3
  *-cache
       description: L1 cache
       physical id: 5
       slot: L1 Cache
       size: 64KiB
       capacity: 64KiB
       capabilities: synchronous internal write-back data
       configuration: level=1
  *-memory
       description: System Memory
       physical id: 26
       slot: System board or motherboard
       size: 4GiB
     *-bank:0
          description: SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1600 MHz (0.6 ns)
          product: M471B5173EB0-YK0
          vendor: Samsung
          physical id: 0
          serial: 00111043
          slot: ChannelA-DIMM0
          size: 4GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 1600MHz (0.6ns)
     *-bank:1
          description: Project-Id-Version: lshwReport-Msgid-Bugs-To: FULL NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS>PO-Revision-Date: 2012-02-05 00:26+0000Last-Translator: Andi Chandler <Unknown>Language-Team: English (United Kingdom) <en_GB@li.org>MIME-Version: 1.0Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bitX-Launchpad-Export-Date: 2018-07-12 13:19+0000X-Generator: Launchpad (build 18719)Project-Id-Version: lshwReport-Msgid-Bugs-To: FULL NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS>PO-Revision-Date: 2012-02-05 00:26+0000Last-Translator: Andi Chandler <Unknown>Language-Team: English (United Kingdom) <en_GB@li.org>MIME-Version: 1.0Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bitX-Launchpad-Export-Date: 2018-07-12 13:19+0000X-Generator: Launchpad (build 18719) [empty]
          physical id: 1
          slot: ChannelA-DIMM1
     *-bank:2
          description: Project-Id-Version: lshwReport-Msgid-Bugs-To: FULL NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS>PO-Revision-Date: 2012-02-05 00:26+0000Last-Translator: Andi Chandler <Unknown>Language-Team: English (United Kingdom) <en_GB@li.org>MIME-Version: 1.0Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bitX-Launchpad-Export-Date: 2018-07-12 13:19+0000X-Generator: Launchpad (build 18719)Project-Id-Version: lshwReport-Msgid-Bugs-To: FULL NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS>PO-Revision-Date: 2012-02-05 00:26+0000Last-Translator: Andi Chandler <Unknown>Language-Team: English (United Kingdom) <en_GB@li.org>MIME-Version: 1.0Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bitX-Launchpad-Export-Date: 2018-07-12 13:19+0000X-Generator: Launchpad (build 18719) [empty]
          physical id: 2
          slot: ChannelB-DIMM0
     *-bank:3
          description: Project-Id-Version: lshwReport-Msgid-Bugs-To: FULL NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS>PO-Revision-Date: 2012-02-05 00:26+0000Last-Translator: Andi Chandler <Unknown>Language-Team: English (United Kingdom) <en_GB@li.org>MIME-Version: 1.0Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bitX-Launchpad-Export-Date: 2018-07-12 13:19+0000X-Generator: Launchpad (build 18719)Project-Id-Version: lshwReport-Msgid-Bugs-To: FULL NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS>PO-Revision-Date: 2012-02-05 00:26+0000Last-Translator: Andi Chandler <Unknown>Language-Team: English (United Kingdom) <en_GB@li.org>MIME-Version: 1.0Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bitX-Launchpad-Export-Date: 2018-07-12 13:19+0000X-Generator: Launchpad (build 18719) [empty]
          physical id: 3
          slot: ChannelB-DIMM1
  *-memory UNCLAIMED
       description: Memory controller
       product: Sunrise Point-LP PMC
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.2
       version: 21
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz (30.3ns)
       capabilities: bus_master
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:a1324000-a1327fff
```

Comment: You are supposed to run `lshw` as root. No description of occupied RAM slots is seen. One thing that sticks out is `-memory UNCLAIMED`, which indicates a possible hardware issue. Run it again as `sudo lshw -C memory`. Also run `uname -a`.

Comment: so no solution to this. will have to reinstall the OS then

Comment: You have an older version of the kernel, 4.15.0-43 whereas you should now have 4.15.0-45. Your memory controller seems to have been identified but no driver provided for it. Run Software Updater (found in /usr/share/applications), and see if that fixes your issue first before a re-install.